# How to avoid UnicodeDecodeError when working with differently encoded files?

Tags: python, encoding

I have to merge ASCII files containing data sets into one, monolithic file. I'm using the standard procedure to perform a line by line merging:

```
for in_filename in os.listdir(w_dir):
    if in_filename.endswith(".scd"):
        write_message("\nAdding '" + in_filename + "' to '" + out_filename + "' ... ", "black")
        with open(out_filename, 'a', encoding="utf-8") as f_out, fileinput.input(in_filename) as f_in:
            for scd_count, line in enumerate(f_in):
                f_out.write(line)
```

The problem is, that the ASCII files I've to merge are encoded differently. When I open them with a text editor which is able to recognise the encoding automatically I see utf-8, ISO 8859-15, ISO 8859-1 and who knows what else. So sooner or later my program will run into a UnicodeDecodeError, no matter what kind of encoding I explicitly tell Python to use. Is there a way to avoid this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The [chardet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet/3.0.2) library is useful to guess file encodings.

Comment: This might work but unfortunately, according to the FAQ, it seems to be too slow. I need to merge lots of files with a total of more than 150.000 lines. I also think that this lib is inefficient because it tries to guess the encoding based on the language used in a file. But my files just contain a comparatively small header which might have language specific text while the majority consists of pure data (numbers and chars).

Comment: @Grendel there's also [cchardet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cchardet/2.0.1) though I've never tried it.

Comment: Hi there, I just want to add that I found another working solution by using the openhook keyword to change the encoding while reading the file:    with open(out_filename, 'a', errors="ignore") as f_out, fileinput.input(in_filename, openhook=fileinput.hook_encoded("latin-1")) as f_in: